# Unable to install tkinter with pyenv Pythons on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyenv

Versions of Python installed via pyenv fail to import `tkinter`:

```
※ python
Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb 29 2020, 11:45:59)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/factor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
>>>
```

or you might get a message about the header version doesn't match the binary:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/factor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4552, in _test
    root = Tk()
  File "/Users/factor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2263, in __init__
    self._loadtk()
  File "/Users/factor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2279, in _loadtk
    raise RuntimeError("tk.h version (%s) doesn't match libtk.a version (%s)"
RuntimeError: tk.h version (8.6) doesn't match libtk.a version (8.5)
```

Comment: For an in-depth explanation of how system and non-system Pythons interact with tkinter and why this issue occurs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105219/39396).

Answer (score 129):

TL;DR set the env. vars. mentioned in `tcl-tk`'s caveats **and** [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375#issuecomment-533182043) when installing new Pythons via pyenv to get `tkinter`.

First, ensure you have the latest `tcl-tk` via homebrew and then pay attention to its caveats:

```
※ brew install tcl-tk
※ brew info tcl-tk
tcl-tk: stable 8.6.10 (bottled) [keg-only]
...
==> Caveats
tcl-tk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because tk installs some X11 headers and macOS provides an (older) Tcl/Tk.

If you need to have tcl-tk first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find tcl-tk you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"

For pkg-config to find tcl-tk you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"
...
```

You'll also need to know about pyenv's `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS`, `--with-tcltk-includes`, and `--with-tcltk-libs`, e.g. from [this comment](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375#issuecomment-533182043).

Next, reinstall Python with the environment variables active:

```
※ pyenv uninstall 3.8.1
※ env \
  PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/bin:$PATH" \
  LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib/pkgconfig" \
  CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
  PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'" \
  pyenv install 3.8.1
```

It should work now:

```
※ pyenv global 3.8.1
※ python
Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb 29 2020, 11:56:10)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.TclVersion, tkinter.TkVersion
(8.6, 8.6)
>>> tkinter._test()
# You should get a GUI
```

If you get the following error, you might be missing the `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS` env. var. above.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/factor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4552, in _test
    root = Tk()
  File "/Users/factor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2263, in __init__
    self._loadtk()
  File "/Users/factor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2279, in _loadtk
    raise RuntimeError("tk.h version (%s) doesn't match libtk.a version (%s)"
RuntimeError: tk.h version (8.6) doesn't match libtk.a version (8.5)
```

Comment: For the record this worked out-of-the-box on Linux (Debian 10) as well. The only difference is that the output of `brew info` was a bit different.

Comment: after I did this, I cannot install python anymore, it shows: BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.1 using python-build 20180424)

Comment: @BergP you will probably need to provide more of the error message. I would recommend creating a new question that references this answer.  You can link to your question from this answer.

Comment: What saved me was installing the `tk-devel` package. I already had python3-tkinter installed but it wasn't enough. After installing the tk-devel package I could successfully install python version via `pyenv install <version>` command without errors.

Answer (score 53):

Here is **step by step guide** to make `tkinter` (and IDLE) work if you use `pyenv` for Python environments management on macOS:

1. install `tcl-tk` with Homebrew. In shell run `brew install tcl-tk`
2. in shell run `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
3. reload shell by quitting `Terminal` app or run `source ~/.zshrc`
4. after reloaded check that `tcl-tk` is in `$PATH`. Run `echo $PATH | grep --color=auto tcl-tk`. As the result you should see your $PATH contents with `tcl-tk` highlighted
5. now we run three commands from Homebrew's output from step #1

   1. in shell run `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"`
   2. in shell run `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"`
   3. in shell run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"`
6. if you have your Python version already installed with `pyenv` then uninstall it with `pyenv uninstall <your python version>`. E.g. `pyenv uninstall 3.8.2`
7. set environment variable that will be used by `python-build`. In shell run `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'"`
   *Note: in future use `tck-tk` version that actually installed with Homebrew. At the moment of posting `8.6` was the actual*
8. finally install Python with `pyenv` with `pyenv install <version>`. E.g. `pyenv install 3.8.2`

**Test**

1. in shell run `pyenv global <verion that you've just installed>`
2. now check IDLE. In shell run `idle`. You should see IDLE window without any warnings and "text printed in red".

[image: IDLE window run from Terminal. No warnings]

3. now check `tkinter`. In shell run `python -m tkinter -c "tkinter._test()"`. You should see test window like on the image:

[image: tkinter test window]

That's it!

**My environment:**

check this is something went wrong executing steps above:

1. macOS Catalina
2. `zsh` (included in macOS Catalina) = **"shell" above**
3. Homebrew (installed with instructions from Homebrew official website)
4. `pyenv` (installed with Homebrew and PATH updated according to `pyenv` official readme from GitHub)
5. Python `3.8.x` - `3.9.x` (installed with `pyenv install <version>` command)

Comment: This was very helpful! I was able to do it in fewer steps by simply using the `env` approach (i.e., no need to edit ~/.zshrc to add all the exports):

`env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6' --enable-shared" pyenv install 3.8.5`

I added --enable-shared since PyInstaller needs it. If you don't need it:

`env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'" pyenv install 3.8.5`

Comment: Thanks. This saved my life.

Comment: Very interesting. But enough there for me to think "nope" - I'll do without idle. Python infrastructure is a complete and utter mess.

Comment: I got the same error message as Carl G. Then I tried this method and it works for me. The step 7 is the key to solve the problem in this post, where you need to point `python-build` to use the correct version of tcl-tk before you run `pyenv install 3.x.x`

Comment: I tried this on an M1 Mac, but unfortunately the last step "pyenv install 3.x.x" (where I did 3.7.9) gives a "BUILD FAILURE". I guess it's some complicated M1 Mac issue and I'll have to use home-brew in x86 mode but that's annoying...

Comment: For those using asdf in place of pyenv above, I recently upgraded asdf via homebrew to v0.10.2 and it broke all file paths within /Users/<my user>/.asdf/shims/*. I had to manually open each file under this directory and replace the /0.10.1/ in the file path with /0.10.2/. Not sure why this happened...

Answer (score 11):

At the time of this writing, it appears that `tcl-tk` is no longer keg-only and, therefore, setting environment variables is no longer needed:

```
※ brew info tcl-tk
==> tcl-tk: stable 8.6.13 (bottled)
...
==> Caveats
The sqlite3_analyzer binary is in the `sqlite-analyzer` formula.
==> Analytics
...
```

Indeed, I was able to provide `pyenv` with `tkinter` and solve the poster's problem simply by running:

```
※ pyenv uninstall <python version>
※ brew install tcl-tk
※ pyenv install <python version>
```

(FWIW, I am using MacOS Ventura on an Apple silicon processor.)

Comment: On an Apple M1 in 2023, this seems to be the best way to fix this!

Comment: I also confirm that this works flawlessly on MacOs Ventura. The other methods are overcomplicating everything and I'm glad that I scrolled enough in order to find a better approach.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work on macOS Sonoma. Still get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Comment: @Ben - on macOS Sonoma as well, and this did not work for me either.  I then also tried setting various environment variables as described in other answers.  That also did not work.  Running on an M1 Mac.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS Big Sur (11.2.3), Carl G's answer didn't work for me because I got a zlib error. Building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556829/6732127) and [this blog post](https://blog.ferstar.org/post/issue-35/), I found success with

```bash
brew install bzip2
export LDFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/lib -L brew --prefix bzip2/lib"
export CFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include -L brew --prefix bzip2/include"
export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6' --enable-framework"
pyenv install 3.8.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to install `tkinter` through pyenv. I was able to fix it using the following in case someone has the same problem and still want to stick with `pyenv`.

**The Fix**

1. I followed @nickolay instructions to install `tkinter` and set the path the proper way.
2. Then, I installed anaconda3-2020.07 using the `pyenv install anaconda3-2020.07` command.
3. Because I am using pyenv python 3.8.6 **globally**: I navigated to the folder I want to use tkinter and used the `anaconda3-2020.07` **locally** by utilizing the command `pyenv local anaconda3-2020.07`to use this version of pyenv in that specific folder. It ran without errors!

**Note:** I am using the following script in the `.bash_profile` to trigger the virtualenv automatically when cd the desired directory

```sh
# manage python version using pyenv
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

# add pyenv virtualenv
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Answer (score -1):

For Python 3.9 and above version, you can use the following formula

[brew install python-tk@3.9](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python-tk@3.9#default)

It will instal python@3.9 and tcl-tk and bind them for you.

Comment: This doesn't help when using pyenv