# Unable to install python 3.11.4 with tkinter via pyenv on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv

I'm receiving the following error trying to install python `3.11.4` via `pyenv` on `MacOS Ventura 13.5.2 (22G91)`:

```console
foo@bar:~$ pyenv install 3.11.4
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.11.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/Python-3.11.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.4...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
WARNING: The Python tkinter extension was not compiled and GUI subsystem has been detected. Missing the Tk toolkit?
Installed Python-3.11.4 to /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4
```

at the same time, I'm able to install python `3.10.4` via `pyenv` just fine:

```console
foo@bar:~$ pyenv install 3.10.4
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.4/Python-3.10.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.4...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.10.4 to /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4
```

While I was searching for an answer, I found this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61879759/14688566

I've tried some of the recommended approaches like this one (uninstall, install with some env vars):

```console
foo@bar:~$ pyenv uninstall 3.11.4
pyenv: remove /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4? [y|N] y
pyenv: 3.11.4 uninstalled

foo@bar:~$ env \
PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/bin:$PATH" \
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib" \
CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib/pkgconfig" \
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib -ltcl8.6.13 -ltk8.6.13'" \
pyenv install 3.11.4

python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.11.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/Python-3.11.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.4...
python-build: use tcl-tk from $PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
WARNING: The Python tkinter extension was not compiled and GUI subsystem has been detected. Missing the Tk toolkit?
Installed Python-3.11.4 to /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4
```

But it's not working either.

As far as I understand, `pyenv` successfully picks up homebrew's `tcl-tk`, so that's not an issue. According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804235/14688566) it appears `tcl-tk` is no longer keg-only and, therefore, setting environment variables is no longer needed.
In fact, I don't see any caveats like *"tcl-tk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local"* when I'm running `brew info tcl-tk` (as far as I undestand, that's the issue faced by the majority of commenters there and the fix for this is running pyenv install along with those environment variables).

---

Here are the outputs of `brew info` for `tcl-tk`, `python-tk` (not sure I even need this one installed tbh) and `pyenv` packages installed on my machine (all of them are latest versions) along with the `brew ---version` output:

```console
foo@bar:~$ brew info tcl-tk
==> tcl-tk: stable 8.6.13 (bottled)
Tool Command Language
https://www.tcl-lang.org
Conflicts with:
  page (because both install `page` binaries)
/usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.13_5 (3,064 files, 52.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-09-12 at 20:45:30
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/t/tcl-tk.rb
License: TCL
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl@3 ✔
==> Caveats
The sqlite3_analyzer binary is in the `sqlite-analyzer` formula.
==> Analytics
install: 57,088 (30 days), 173,897 (90 days), 333,561 (365 days)
install-on-request: 27,654 (30 days), 89,791 (90 days), 164,180 (365 days)
build-error: 6 (30 days)
```

```console
foo@bar:~$ brew info python-tk
==> python-tk@3.11: stable 3.11.5 (bottled)
Python interface to Tcl/Tk
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python-tk@3.11/3.11.5 (5 files, 131.7KB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-09-12 at 11:11:06
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/p/python-tk@3.11.rb
License: Python-2.0
==> Dependencies
Required: python@3.11 ✔, tcl-tk ✔
==> Analytics
install: 7,261 (30 days), 16,597 (90 days), 32,528 (365 days)
install-on-request: 7,255 (30 days), 16,583 (90 days), 32,505 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

```console
foo@bar:~$ brew info pyenv
==> pyenv: stable 2.3.26 (bottled), HEAD
Python version management
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/2.3.26 (1,110 files, 3.3MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-09-13 at 09:42:44
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/p/pyenv.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Required: autoconf ✔, openssl@3 ✔, pkg-config ✔, readline ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 109,431 (30 days), 278,276 (90 days), 531,993 (365 days)
install-on-request: 108,805 (30 days), 276,683 (90 days), 528,966 (365 days)
build-error: 3 (30 days)
```

```console
foo@bar:~$ brew --version
Homebrew 4.1.11
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 8e188d78fe0; last commit 2023-09-13)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 862ffb4b59; last commit 2023-09-13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reported this issue to pyenv team:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2790

should be fixed with this PR:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/pull/2791